# Wrapping a promise function with Async function and using awaits, what to do with '.then'?

Tags: javascript

So im currently learning how to use Aync functions and awaits in JS and I wanted to practice by wrapping a promise in an async function and use awaits. Heres the code im trying to change,

```
    let meatwad = new Promise(function(r, rr) {
      setTimeout(() => r({Arch_Duke_of_NY:"A#1"}), 3000);
    });
      meatwad.then(console.log)
      
      meatwad.then(m => console.log("My name is "+m.Arch_Duke_of_NY))
      meatwad.then(function(n) {
        n["boxy"] = "brown"
        return n
      })
      .then(function (w){
          console.log(w.boxy + " is "+ w.Arch_Duke_of_NY)
      })
```

So I understand that Async and awaits are meant to deal with all the nesting and the .then's but Im stumped on what to do when I get to the '.then' resolves. Heres what I got although I didnt change much:

```
 async function f(){
    let meatwad = new Promise(function(r, rr) {
      setTimeout(() => r({Arch_Duke_of_NY:"A#1"}), 3000);
    });
      let result = await meatwad;
    
        console.log(result);
        
        meatwad.then(m => console.log("My name is "+m.Arch_Duke_of_NY))
        meatwad.then(function(n) {
          n["boxy"] = "brown"
          return n
        })
        .then(function (w){
            console.log(w.boxy + " is "+ w.Arch_Duke_of_NY)
        })
      }
    
      f();
```

It feels like Im just adding more code for no reason at this point. If you guys could give me some tips and maybe explain why Async and awaits would make the code more efficient/ elegant. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async/await is only an abstraction that makes your code look more like synchronous one. Once you get a promise you are ready to go. If I was going to rewrite your code I with async/await it should look something like below:

```
function meatwad() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({Arch_Duke_of_NY:"A#1"}), 3000);
    });
}

async function asyncContext() {
    // At this point JS says to the runtime that this can take a while, so this task goes to the famous event loop till it gets resolved
    const meatwadAnswer = await meatwad();
    // After 3 seconds the program would return at this point (this gets back to the top of the stack) and continue to execute the code synchronously until it finds another await...
    console.log(meatwadAnswer);
    console.log(`My name is ${meatwadAnswer['Arch_Duke_of_NY']}`);
    meatwadAnswer['boxy'] = 'brown';
    console.log(`${meatwadAnswer.boxy} is ${meatwadAnswer['Arch_Duke_of_NY']}`)
}
```

One more thing is: you don't need to chain **.then()** every time, just use it when you are going to do something that is not synchronous, like fetch data (you don't have to use it if you're only going to log data to you console or to append a prop to your object).

If you want to know how JS manage all this stuff in details, check Philip Roberts explanation at JSConf on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ.

Comment: Great video! and thanks for the help I really appreciate it! So then at that point, what would you say are the main advantages of using async and awaits over .then? And the main advantages of using promises over callbacks. Does this mean that regular callbacks arent really used that much in efficient JS programming?

Comment: Basically code readability is the biggest advantage of async/await. For example, if you have a few async operations one after the other your code would be a little harder for others to understand with **.then()/.catch()** (remember that programmers, write code for others and then for computers). Callbacks are still very used just not that much in asynchronous context anymore, but as parameters to functions such as **.map()**, **forEach()** and **filter()**. An important point that I forgot to mention on the answer is that there is no **.catch()** in async/await, we use try/catch instead.